# 64 битный LInux Ubuntu (PPPoЕ)

Tags: linux

Установил 64 битную Ununtu 11.10. Поднял соединение PPPoE (через терминал). Казалось бы - все замечательно. Но в процессе работы (качания с интернета, обновления), соединение падает. Это происходит с завидной периодичностью и пенять на некий "косяк" не нужно. Плюс на модеме перестает моргать лампочка (та где провод втыкается в порт. На системном блоке такая же есть - когда провод Ethernet втыкаем). Проверил модем и кабели - все в порядке. На Windows все работает безупречно. На Linux Mint 12 (64-bit) та же проблема. Может мне кто-нибудь подсказать, что делать? Привожу данные команды `ifconfig` если нужно.

Когда все хорошо:

```
russia@russia-comp ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:6f:65:fe:f9:16  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1e6f:65ff:fefe:f916/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15822 errors:42 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:23914849 (23.9 MB)  TX bytes:1475906 (1.4 MB)
          Interrupt:41 Base address:0xe000

lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 B)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 B)

ppp0      Link encap:Протокол PPP (Point-to-Point Protocol)  
          inet addr:92.126.32.215  P-t-P:213.228.116.148  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:16621 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15739 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:23439745 (23.4 MB)  TX bytes:1058959 (1.0 MB)
```

Когда нет PPPoe:

```
russia@russia-comp ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:6f:65:fe:f9:16  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1e6f:65ff:fefe:f916/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15822 errors:42 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:23914849 (23.9 MB)  TX bytes:1475906 (1.4 MB)
          Interrupt:41 Base address:0xe000

lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 B)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 B)
```

Comment: А почему большое количество ошибок на eth0? Может проблемы с его драйвером?

Comment: Да вроде все по стандарту. На 11,04 все отлично работало.

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите опцию `debug` (просто слово «`debug`» на отдельной строчке) в `/etc/ppp/options` (или, пожалуй, лучше, peer-файле в `/etc/ppp/peers/`) и посмотрите что происходит на момент разрыва (в сислоге). Если не будет сразу видно в чем дело — запостите лог сюда, обновив вопрос. После отладки не забудьте убрать.

Кроме того, возможно, действительно в ядре сломали драйвер сетевой карты. Такое бывает. Приглядывайте, заодно, в `dmesg` — если там какие-нибудь transmit queue overrun'ы или еще что-то нехорошее — это может пролить свет на суть проблемы.